# R.java can't be modified

Tags: android, r.java-file

I was trying to modify the R.java in android. I deleted the generated java files. After saving, it doesn't seem to change anything. The R.java file i have looks like this

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY. 
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
public final class R {
public static final class attr {
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int myEditText=0x7f050000;
    public static final int myListView=0x7f050001;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int colors=0x7f030000;
    public static final int dimens=0x7f030001;
    public static final int main=0x7f030002;
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
    public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
}
}
```

I wanted to change it, to be more like this one:

```
 /* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.    
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
public final class R {
public static final class attr {
}

public static final class color {
    public static final int notepad_lines=0x7f040001;
    public static final int notepad_margin=0x7f040002;
    public static final int notepad_paper=0x7f040000;
    public static final int notepad_text=0x7f040003;
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int myEditText=0x7f050000;
    public static final int myListView=0x7f050001;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int colors=0x7f030000;
    public static final int dimens=0x7f030001;
    public static final int main=0x7f030002;
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
    public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
}
}
```

It so frustrating every time I save it, it goes back to its old state because it's auto generated . How do I modify it?

Comment: why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: just trying to customize this project i'm working on

Comment: You use the values/color.xml to generate those colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.java is an auto generated file contains all your resources used in project. If you want to change R.java you can't.

You have to add or delete resources, then it will be modified according to your resources present in project.

This is basic thing in Android. You have to read Android Developers documents, then you will get good knowledge about it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify R.java in android it will be generated automatically when we are developing an xml file.... here id numbers will be stored of different views so we can't modify it..

Comment: I figure that out, i had to create xml file in res/values/colors.xml . then typed such                                                               <resources>
  <color name="notepad_paper">#AAFFFF99</color> ... </resources>