# Why cant we modify R.java?

Tags: java, android

I have read in several places that we shouldn't modify R.java. My question is why shouldn't we modify R.java?. What is so important about those Ids that they should not be modified?

Comment: No.. My question is why???.. I already know that its autogenerated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html#detailed-build

Comment: And the Answer to that Question is in the Question linked to above.  Because it is auto-generated, and if you update it by hand your updates will be clobbered.  It it nothing to do with "importance".  It is just the way that part of the Android toolchain works.  The XML and Java need to be in step, and it is done by generating one from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.java is an auto generated file contains all your resources used in project. If you want to change R.java you can't.

You have to add or delete resources, then it will be modified according to your resources present in project.

This is basic thing in Android. You have to read Android Developers documents, then you will get good knowledge about it.

Courtesy :[R.java can't be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615007/r-java-cant-be-modified)

Comment: So... The Ids are generated based on the reources that we use.. So, if i change the Id, I will be indirectly modifying how resources are accessed?

Comment: yes and if you change the id.it will override in next build of application

Answer (score 1):

This is a generated file. It contains all references to your ids you defined in your xml files, to your drawables, strings, etc. Therefore it makes no sense to modify this file!

This also means that all your changes will be gone when the file is generated the next time (e.g. when you add an id)